# Is there file opener for development purposes?

Tags: laravel, file, search, plugins, phpstorm

I'm getting tired of always manually opening my files based on what section of the website I'm working on. So if I type a URL to my website, Firefox or an IDE like PhpStorm will automatically open that file based on the URL in PhpStorm for instance.

Since I'm on a framework (Laravel) it will know exactly which file to open.  Or, I type that URL in PhpStorm somewhere, and it will locate/open the corresponding file.

Is there such a thing in PhpStorm?

Comment: Please provide examples (e.g. this is an URL and IDE should be opening this particular file). But generally speaking -- this looks like framework/library depended action (IDE MUST know how your current project routes requests to resolve what controller/file to open). Laravel support (since you have used it as an example) is provided by a 3rd party plugin .. therefore if anything such feature should be expected from it and not from an IDE that does not give preferences to any specific framework.

Comment: In mean time -- why not use `Navigate | File...` or `Navigate | Class...` (or just `Search Everywhere` that seem to do all kind of searches at once) and just type the class (controller) name... Have you tried it?

Comment: @LazyOne - well this is still manual...i was looking for a more automated solution like the one i stated...

Comment: *"Or, I type that URL in PhpStorm somewhere, and it will locate/open the corresponding file."* You still need to type an URL somewhere ... so not too much of a difference (as for me). The difference though is that in your case you do not need to remember the project structure (what does what) and work with URLs mainly. Not sure if that's a desired way for a developer... but definitely handy if you just starting to work on unknown and big project with many controllers/URLs.

Comment: @LazyOne - exactly...that's what rout file is for, the mappings are there, so we don't need to constantly type/remember that when opening target files...it get's annoying when you got crap load of controllers...

Comment: In that case, how would you open post, put, patch or delete routes?

Comment: well i'll type in the route in phpstorm, then it locates those controllers and opens those files for me, or link those posts/puts/patch etc in browser with tags that phpstorm might understand, and the browser pings phpstorm whenever they're accessed.

Comment: there should be plugins to sync your ide to the browser and your program framework/protocols so these tasks are speeded up and seemless.

Comment: **In any case:** *"Is there such a thing in PhpStorm?"* No. This is very framework specific request. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI -- feel free to make Feature Request and see what devs will say about it.

Comment: Also keep in mind: frameworks may have multiple places where routes might be defined: Laravel can use many `web.php` (main file + any Service provider can provide own; you can even add then during runtime); Symfony can have routes defined in Controller action's PHPDocs in addition to config files (that could be PHP array or XML or Yaml file) etc. Therefore I personally do not see how it might be a PhpStorm core feature here.

Comment: @LazyOne - well have the plugin developers of phpstorm keep up to date with them...